I can't get a marker on the ground under the character to appear and disappear properly
This code creates a marking on the ground under the main player and another standard marking for the "other players" with the condition that both markings appear and disappear depending on the distance between two or more entities (it can be the main player and any other). Interestingly, the marking appears and disappears correctly for others, but not for the main player.
How can I fix this?
public class ProximityMarkerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform MainCharacter; 
    public Sprite MainCharacterMarker; 
    public Sprite DefaultMarker; 
    public float MarkerSize = 20f; 
    public float OtherMarkerSize = 25f; 
    public float FadeDuration = 0.3f; 
    public float VisibilityThreshold = 25f; 

    private CharacterActivationController characterActivationController;
    private GameObject[] AllCharacters;
    private GameObject[] Markers; 

    void Start()
    {
        AllCharacters = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Character");

        Markers = new GameObject[AllCharacters.Length];

        characterActivationController = MainCharacter.GetComponent<CharacterActivationController>();
        if (characterActivationController == null)
        {
            characterActivationController = MainCharacter.gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterActivationController>();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < AllCharacters.Length; i++)
        {
            Markers[i] = new GameObject("Marker" + i);
            SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer = Markers[i].AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

            SpriteRenderer.sprite = AllCharacters[i] == MainCharacter.gameObject ? MainCharacterMarker : DefaultMarker;

            float size = AllCharacters[i] == MainCharacter.gameObject ? MarkerSize : OtherMarkerSize;
            Markers[i].transform.localScale = new Vector3(size, size, size);

            SetMarkerTransparency(Markers[i], 0f);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AllCharacters.Length; i++)
        {
            float Distance = Vector3.Distance(MainCharacter.position, AllCharacters[i].transform.position);

            if (Distance <= VisibilityThreshold)
            {
                FadeInMarker(Markers[i]);
                if (AllCharacters[i] == MainCharacter.gameObject)
                {
                    characterActivationController.ActivateCharacter();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FadeOutMarker(Markers[i]);
                if (AllCharacters[i] == MainCharacter.gameObject)
                {
                    characterActivationController.DeactivateCharacter();
                }
            }

            if (Markers[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color.a > 0f)
            {
                Markers[i].transform.position = new Vector3(AllCharacters[i].transform.position.x, AllCharacters[i].transform.position.y - 1f, AllCharacters[i].transform.position.z);
                Markers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CharacterActivationController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public void ActivateCharacter()
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        public void DeactivateCharacter()
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void SetMarkerTransparency(GameObject Marker, float Alpha)
    {
        SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer = Marker.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        Color Color = SpriteRenderer.color;
        Color.a = Alpha;
        SpriteRenderer.color = Color;
    }

    private void FadeInMarker(GameObject Marker)
    {
        SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer = Marker.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if (SpriteRenderer.color.a < 1f)
        {
            float Alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(SpriteRenderer.color.a + Time.deltaTime / FadeDuration);
            SetMarkerTransparency(Marker, Alpha);
        }
    }

    private void FadeOutMarker(GameObject Marker)
    {
        SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer = Marker.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if (SpriteRenderer.color.a > 0f)
        {
            float Alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(SpriteRenderer.color.a - Time.deltaTime / FadeDuration);
            SetMarkerTransparency(Marker, Alpha);
        }
    }
}

Well, the basics of the code work, but Fade Out doesn't work for the main player, only for the others. I don't know if there would be an extra script or some snippet to at least force the Fade In and Fade Out correctly.

well the test for all characters seems to occur only if the distance between maincharacter and a given player is <visibility, but if you said its the main character not fading, well its always going to have a distance of 0 right if it conforms to being an object with tag character, it will be in the list....

BugFinder is right.  Not sure of your exact setup, but you may be able to stick the fade in into an else statement.  eg. if (character == mainCharacter) .. else FadeIn..
